# My question is how to create a VPD in Oracle with SQL that will also mask data

Tags: sql, oracle, data-masking, vpd

I am trying to create a VPD in Oracle using SQL statements. The purpose of this problem is so an employee could ONLY view records for employees in the same department while masking their coworker's salaries as NULL.

The code for the table being used is as follows

```
create table Employee
(
    ID number primary key,
    DEPT varchar2(25),
    SALARY number(8,2),
    NAME varchar2(25)
);
```

I am unsure what the best way to go about doing this would be.... would it be to create a package and use an application context. I believe getting the table to only display those in same "DEPT" I understand but unsure how to mask the data of those with same DEPT but different ID.

Answer (score 0):

Native RLS will get you close but not totally there.  Using "sec_relevant_cols" will give you the option between

- only seeing the rows that match your predicate, but all values are present
- seeing all the rows, but masking values that do not match your predicate

whereas (if I'm reading correctly) you want to see only predicate matching rows AND mask out some values as well.

You could achieve this with a two-step method

1. Your context contains two keys (say) DEPT and YOUR_ID
2. The RLS policy is "where dept = sys_context(ctx,'DEPT')"
3. You have a view EMP to which that policy is applied, being

   ```
    select 
      id, 
      dept, 
      name,
      case when id = sys_context(ctx,'YOUR_ID') then sal else null end sal
    from EMP_TABLE
   ```

Comment: I'll give it a shot! I was using a context that allowed me to get the DEPT value from whoever is logged! I was unaware I could use it to gain another one as well... is it possible to do that all within the same package?

Comment: Yes, the context is bound to the package, not the keys/values within the context.  A context can have many keys/values.  "USERENV" is a classic example of that